# Magento 2 REST Api with Authorize.net

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, authorize.net

I'm using Magento:2 REST Api in my website, and currently working on the **payment system (Authorize.net)**.

Is it possible to create a transaction ? and place an order with Authorize.net
through the Magento Api after setting up Authorize.net in the admin?

Comment: Yes you can, new Magento checkout page use apis the complete a trasanction. I'm working something similar (paypal payflow). My advise take a look in the checkout page and debug js to see what authorize js file use and take the idea from there.

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear about that, but i'm developing the client using angular (no template), and the Magento integration is done only via REST Api. I couldn't find an api call that uses Authorize.net, or any call to send payment details for that matter.

Comment: You don't. We developed a entire payment flow via angular using PayPal and you are not going to find a API call. You need to set all manually using authorize.net API then you need to send payment info with Magento API call setPaymentInfo. My suggestion is this one, configure authorize.net method in your Magento and use Magento checkout page and debug when Magento call authorize API and try to replicate the same in your angular code.